# Delete a selected div

Tags: javascript, dom

Script explanation : I have a text area which user is typing notes and those notes are added to the DOM (as div elements) . I created an icon inside that divs that when you click on it i want the parent of the icon that is clicked to be removed from the DOM . I achieve this with JQuery , but i cant do it in pure JS. The code i use to achieve this in:

```
$('.fa-window-close').on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log($(this).parents('div')[0]);
                $(this).parents('div')[0].remove();

           });
```

Iam posting a link from gist, its a part code of my project so you can understand what iam trying to achieve.

https://gist.github.com/Clickys/43856fe26ee4c061cf910a9211f0c142

Basically what i want to achieve is , lets assume that we have a button that is creating divs elements inside DOM. Each of this div has an icon(fontawesome) that if we click on it , the selected target should be removed from the DOM(the target div) but not the other divs . I tried to use `event.target` and a lot of things but sadly i couldn't solve this with pure JS.

I tried this

```
closeTolPos.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      var parentEl = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
      parentEl.removeChild(this.parentElement);
      console.log(this.parentElement);
});
```

But it seems that when there are more than 1 element , it doesnt work . It only works if there is one element.

Comment: Please post a fiddle so it will be easy to help you

Comment: Do you want to remove the parent element that contains your `i.fa-window-close`, check this [pen](http://codepen.io/LagartoSeb/pen/jBdzmm), is what you want?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Yes is what i want to achieve but i got this error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Comment: Are you removing the child from the `body` as parent element?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes i used ur code to locate the icon. then run the forEach() method for each element and added the eventListener to each element and then querySelector the body .removeChild(this.parentNode);

Comment: its strange because i want to achieve the same thing as your codepen. But it doesnt work hmm

Comment: maybe can you check the https://gist.github.com/Clickys/43856fe26ee4c061cf910a9211f0c142 , when i created the element Nodes and text nodes iv done something wierd?

Comment: I saw in your gist you have the `$('.fa-window-close').on('click'...` inside your `notesTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click'`, the `fa-window-close` listener must be outside of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139696/discussion-between-christodoulou-andreas-and-sebastian-palma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make some changes and now the code works:

```
 (function() {
    document.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
      if (e.target.closest('.notesDecoration')) {
        e.target.closest('.notesDecoration').parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
      }
    });     
 })();
```

Now click event is binded to a document, so the element exists, when the page is loaded. Then I check if the clicked element was the element, which was recently created and added to DOM.